# Error in shutting down the Google Pub sub publisher

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, google-publisher-tag

I have started the publisher of google pub sub using the coding[1].After finishing the publisher I shut down the publisher as[2].But when I run I'm getting an error[3]saying that the publisher is not properly shutdown.
I'm using pubsub 1.61.0 version.
Is there any way to handle this error?

[1]

```
public class PublisherExample {

  // use the default project id
  private static final String PROJECT_ID = ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();

  /** Publish messages to a topic.
   * @param args topic name, number of messages
   */
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // topic id, eg. "my-topic"
    String topicId = args[0];
    int messageCount = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.of(PROJECT_ID, topicId);
    Publisher publisher = null;
    List<ApiFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
      // Create a publisher instance with default settings bound to the topic
      publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();

      for (int i = 0; i < messageCount; i++) {
        String message = "message-" + i;

        // convert message to bytes
        ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
        PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
            .setData(data)
            .build();

        // Schedule a message to be published. Messages are automatically batched.
        ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
        futures.add(future);
      }
    } finally {
      // Wait on any pending requests
      List<String> messageIds = ApiFutures.allAsList(futures).get();

      for (String messageId : messageIds) {
        System.out.println(messageId);
      }

      if (publisher != null) {
        // When finished with the publisher, shutdown to free up resources.
        publisher.shutdown();
        publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[2]

```
if (publisher != null) {
  resources.
    publisher.shutdown();
  publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

[3]

```
io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper$ManagedChannelReference cleanQueue
SEVERE: *~*~*~ Channel ManagedChannelImpl{logId=9, target=pubsub.googleapis.com:443} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
    Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper$ManagedChannelReference.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:103)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:53)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:44)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:419)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:254)
```